# A large file containing 1 million integers, what would be the fastest way to find the most occurring?

Tags: algorithm, frequency

Basic approach would be to use an array or a hashmap to create a historgram of numbers and select the most frequent.

In this case let's assume that all the numbers from the file cannot be loaded into the main memory.

One way I can think of is to sort using external merge/quick sort and then chunk by chunk calculate the frequency. As they are sorted, we don't have to worry about the number appearing again after the sequence with a number finishes.

Is there a better and more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is this an interview question? Why would one million integers not fit into memory?

Comment: What is the range of numbers

Comment: Stream it using Unix operators... Use `head -n1` to find the max. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170043/148686

Comment: Yes, this an interview question. The range of the numbers is not known.

Comment: @kevmo314 Because you're working on a system that has very limited available memory? Or, let's just make it a trillion long integers. The idea is that you have more data than can fit into available memory. The actual numbers don't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a million isn't so much anymore, so lets assume we're talking about several billion integers.

In that case, I would suggest that you hash them and partition them into **2^N** buckets (separate files or preallocated parts of the same file) using the top **N** bits of their hash values.

You would choose **N** so that the resulting buckets were highly likely to be small enough to process in memory.

You would then process each bucket by counting the occurrences of each unique value in a hash table or similar.

In the unlikely event that a bucket has too many unique values to fit in RAM, repartition using the next **N** bits of the hash and try again.

Comment: Any hash function can be used, and a good one is less likely to result in an uneven partition.